# Tracking drop column progress in Oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have issued following statement in Oracle on a huge table (1.8 TB size):

```
alter table drop unused columns checkpoint
```

It has been running for almost 10 days now, crashing a couple of times due to lack of memory.

I resumed it with :

```
alter table drop columns continue
```

How can I track the progress and possibly get an estimate of the finish time?

I tried querying v$session_longops but there are no records for this session.

Comment: Don't you know which columns you want to drop?

Comment: How is that relevant to my question?

Comment: If you specifically want to know how to monitor progress, then it is not relevant and I apologize. If, on the other hand, you MUST delete unused columns and you don't want to spend such a INFINITE amount of time, then it is very relevant. Your turn now.

Comment: I'm still not following, but yes, I know which columns I want to drop - I marked them as unused.

Comment: In that case, you may try copying the contents of the current table into a new one WITHOUT the superfluous columns, and then drop the old and rename the new. This approach will be faster if the 1.8TB are filled with data and not slim records (i.e. if you have a huge amount of records with very little data, you might find yourself in more or less the same situation). Also, check if it is worth defining the indices of the new table before or after the process. Just a suggestion, not a **golden** solution.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but given that nobody actually ever answered it, here's what I came up with when I ran into the same problem:

```html
select v.*, to_char(100*"Processed"/"# of Blocks", '990D000000') "% Complete"
from (select sid, serial#, status, event, p1text, p1, p2text, p2, p3text, p3, x.segment_name, x.extent_id,
            (select sum(case
                          when p2 not between block_id and block_id + blocks - 1 then blocks
                          else p2 - block_id
                        end)
             from dba_extents x2
             where x2.segment_name = x.segment_name
             and   extent_id <= x.extent_id) "Processed",
            (select sum(blocks)
             from   dba_extents
             where  segment_name = x.segment_name) "# of Blocks"
     from   v$session s 
     left join dba_extents x on p1 = file_id and p2 between block_id and block_id + blocks - 1
     where  (sid, serial#) in ((15,40610))
) v
```

Basically, I'm taking the P2 value (Block #) from the wait event on the session doing the drop, and identifying where within the table's list of segments the process is at.

There is some work left to the reader here, as this assumes that

1. You know the session and serial#
2. That "db file sequential read" activities are, in fact sequential.
3. That the session isn't swapping between multiple files
4. That the tablespace the table resides in isn't split across multiple files

One could probably also only look at which extent the session was in compared to the total number of extents in the segment to give a rough estimate of progress as well...

Hopefully somebody else can find this helpful, even if only as a breadcrumb to building a better solution.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Good query above. I modified the query a bit:

```
select
  v.*,
  Round(100*"Processed"/"# of Blocks", 2) "% Complete"
from (
  select
    sid,
    serial#,
    status,
    event,
    p1text,
    p1,
    p2text,
    p2,
    p3text,
    p3,
    x.segment_name,
    x.partition_name,
    x.extent_id,
    ( select
        sum(
          case
            when p2.partition_position < p.partition_position
              then x2.blocks
            when ( x2.partition_name is null or
                   p2.partition_position = p.partition_position) and
                 x2.file_id < x.file_id
              then x2.blocks
            when ( x2.partition_name is null or
                   p2.partition_position = p.partition_position) and
                 x2.file_id = x.file_id and
                 x2.block_id < x.block_id
              then x2.blocks
            when ( x2.partition_name is null or
                   p2.partition_position = p.partition_position) and
                 x2.file_id = x.file_id and
                 x2.block_id = x.block_id and
                 s.p2 < x2.block_id + x2.blocks
              then s.p2 - x2.block_id
          end
        )
      from DBA_EXTENTS x2
        left join DBA_TAB_PARTITIONS p2
          on p2.table_owner = x2.owner and
             p2.table_name = x2.segment_name and
             p2.partition_name = x2.partition_name
      where x2.segment_name = x.segment_name
    ) as "Processed",
    ( select
        sum(x2.blocks)
      from DBA_EXTENTS x2
      where x2.segment_name = x.segment_name
    ) as "# of Blocks"
  from V$SESSION s
    left join DBA_EXTENTS x
      on s.p1 = x.file_id and
         s.p2 between x.block_id and x.block_id + x.blocks - 1
    left join DBA_TAB_PARTITIONS p
      on p.table_owner = x.owner and
         p.table_name = x.segment_name and
         p.partition_name = x.partition_name
  where
    --(sid, serial#) in ((84,23431)) or
    s.event = 'db file scattered read'
) v
```